# LaTeX CV, change pagenumber position

Tags: margins, koma-script, resume

I am preparing my CV in germany using the `currvita` Package. 
Unfortunally the pagenumbers on the bottom of the page are not really at the bottom of the page. There is something like 5 cm between the "real" bottom of the page and the number. My problem is that I don't know how to change it. 
I use this code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % T1-encoded fonts: auch Wörter mit Umlauten trennen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{currvita}


\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}


\usepackage[final]{graphicx}  % um Graphiken einzubinden
\usepackage{picins} %fuer bild einfuegen


\begin{document}
\parpic[rs]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{ild.jpg}}
\begin{cv}{Lebenslauf}
  \begin{cvlist}{Persönliche Daten}
  \item xxx
  \item Tel.:~+xxx\\
    E"~Mail:~xxx
  \item Geb.~xxx\\
    xxx
  \end{cvlist}

    \begin{cvlist}{Universität}
        \item[xx/20xx--xx] xxx
    \end{cvlist}

  \begin{cvlist}{Weiterführende Schule}
        \item[xx/xxxx--xx/xxxx] xxx
  \end{cvlist}

  \begin{cvlist}{xxxx}
        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
    \end{itemize}

        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
        \end{itemize}

        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx


        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
    \end{itemize}


        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
    \end{itemize}


        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
    \end{itemize}


        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
    \end{itemize}


        \item[xx/xxxx--aktuell] xxx
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxxxxx
        \item xxxxxx
    \end{itemize}

    \end{cvlist}




  \cvplace{Internet}
  \date{04.~Februar~2013}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
\endinput
```

Please ignore the wrong position of the xxs. What matters is the pagenumber and the position and (normally) this example should work

Comment: Did you try to change value of `\textheight`?

Comment: Can you please complete your given code snippet to an complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can compile your MWE on our computers and check the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the pagenumber comes from the used KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` which chooses a typographical very good typing area. In the documentation of [KOMA-Script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf) you can read this. I gave you the link to the German documentation, as you seems to be a German. In chapter "Satzspiegelberechnung mit typearea.sty" you can read how to change the type setting area with KOMA-Script. On page 34, table 2.1 you can read the used margins used with the document class option `div`, for example `div=15`.

Add the needed value in your MWE and try again, for example with:

```
\documentclass[%
  ngerman       % neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
 ,fontsize=11pt % Schriftgröße des Massentextes
 ,paper=a4      % Din A4, Voreinstellung 
 ,DIV=15        % Berechnung des Satzspiegels, siehe Dokumentation Seite 34, Tabelle 2.1
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe} % shows the used typing area and margins for testing
```

Package `showframe` shows you your used margin with black lines on the paper. Comment it out for printing the final CV.

BTW: in your given MWE is a `\end{itemize}` missing. Use image `example-image-a.jpg` from the package MWE to make your MWE compiliable for all (you must have installed package [MWE](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) on your computer (very useful I think) but must not load it.

PS: Do you know package [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)? I used it to build my own cv with it.